# Sort by multiple duplicate rows, then delete

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a query that I have been working on in phpmyadmin that sorts entries based on a duplicate geometric locations,

The Query looks like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) c 
FROM `spatial_locations`
WHERE 1
GROUP BY x,y,z HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY `c` DESC
```

And it returns a proper result ordered by 'c'

What I would like to do is further expand upon this query to go through the results, and delete any entries where C > 10 ordered by date (basically make any entries to the system older than the most recent 10 go away)

Is this possible the way I am suggesting it or am I on the completely wrong track?

Answer (score 0):

*delete any entries where C > 10 ....* with that do you to perform a `DELETE` operation (OR) just exclude those records from your `SELECT` resultset. If you just want to remove from select query resultset then you can probably just modify your `HAVING` condition saying

```
HAVING c <= 10
```

Well, to `DELETE` you can have those rows inserted in a `TEMPORARY` table and use that table instead like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test AS
SELECT some_unique_id_column, COUNT(*) c 
FROM `spatial_locations`
WHERE 1
GROUP BY x,y,z 
HAVING c <= 10
ORDER BY `c` DESC
```

Then perform the `DELETE` operation like

```
DELETE FROM `spatial_locations`
WHERE some_unique_id_column IN (
SELECT some_unique_id_column FROM test);
```

Comment: When I replace `SELECT` with `DELETE` I get an error. That also doesnt take into account the date column.

Comment: NO, you can't delete from a query resultset.

Comment: Thats the question then. Can you please help me determine how to remove these results in the best manner possible?

Comment: So, how does a temporary table differ? Do I have to chain the queries or do I then reference the temporary table? EDIT: I am coming back with an empty result set when I run yours as is.

Comment: You will have to temp table / auxilary table since you can use the same table in subquery from which you are trying to delete. That's a constraint posed by MySQL. If you are getting empty set then check if the conditions are fine.

Comment: Which conditions? I have `WHERE` set to `1`
Its basically the same query as before isnt it? Just outputting to a temporary table. But I am unfamiliar with temporary tables... do I have to do something special to work with them?

Comment: I mean the condition `HAVING c <= 10`. does it what you are looking after else change it accordingly.

Comment: Alright, so I have figured out how to make it work (some issues with using phpmyadmin and temp tables. Now, how can I sort the results and either only delete results older than a certain date. Or delete all but the most recent 10? Do I put those conditions where the `having` is?